# is there any way to solve python version conflict

Tags: python

I am a newbie to python and today I found the python dependencies is so easy to get conflict, each package need to run in a small version period, is there any better way or tricks to handle the version conflict?

```
#8 75.87 The conflict is caused by:
#8 75.87     The user requested opencv-python-headless==4.7.0.72
#8 75.87     rembg 2.0.30 depends on opencv-python-headless~=4.6.0.66
#8 75.87
#8 75.87 To fix this you could try to:
#8 75.87 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
#8 75.87 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

I am using this command to generate the `requirement.txt`:

```
pip3 freeze > requirement.txt
```

and this is the output:

```
fastapi==0.95.0
openai==0.27.0
sse-starlette==1.3.3
SQLAlchemy~=1.4.6
pydantic~=1.10.5
rembg==2.0.30
pillow~=9.3.0
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiosignal==1.3.1
anyio==3.6.2
async-timeout==4.0.2
asyncer==0.0.2
attrs==22.2.0
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
coloredlogs==15.0.1
filetype==1.2.0
flatbuffers==23.3.3
frozenlist==1.3.3
h11==0.14.0
httptools==0.5.0
humanfriendly==10.0
idna==3.4
ImageHash==4.3.1
imageio==2.27.0
lazy_loader==0.2
llvmlite==0.39.1
mpmath==1.3.0
multidict==6.0.4
networkx==3.1
numba==0.56.2
numpy==1.23.5
onnxruntime==1.14.1
opencv-python-headless~=4.6.0.66
packaging==23.0
platformdirs==3.2.0
pooch==1.7.0
protobuf==4.22.1
pydantic==1.10.7
PyMatting==1.1.8
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python-multipart==0.0.6
PyWavelets==1.4.1
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.28.2
scikit-image~=0.19.3
scipy~=1.9.3
sniffio==1.3.0
starlette==0.26.1
sympy==1.11.1
tifffile==2023.3.21
tqdm~=4.64.1
typing_extensions==4.5.0
urllib3==1.26.15
uvicorn~=0.20.0
uvloop==0.17.0
watchdog~=2.1.9
watchfiles==0.19.0
websockets==11.0
yarl==1.8.2
psycopg2-binary==2.9.6
```

now I found a issue that the dependencies are totally chaos and it seem impossible to tweak the dependencies one by one. is there anyway like one key to fix the dependencies?

Comment: Update rembg to a newer version, it's looser in its latest version. *In general:* yeah, this conflict is always a possibility.

Answer (score -1):

Use a package manager: You can use a package manager like Anaconda, which allows you to create isolated environments with specific Python versions and packages. This way, you can manage multiple Python versions and packages without conflicts.

Comment: I am using pip now. I will try to use anaconda.

Comment: This still won't allow you to have conflicting packages *within* one environment.